# Paste Special excel to powerpoint keeps giving 424 object required error when trying to resize

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

So i've been trying to resize a linked chart that starts in excel and is pasted to a PPT slide with the paste special method. Unfortunately I keep running in to the "424 Object Required" error regardless of what I do when I try to call the method that sets height/width/etc... Ive copy/pasted this exact code from another SO post and the error persists, specifically on the .height = 200 line

```
Sub CopyDataToPPT()

    Dim objslide
    Dim objRange As Range
    Dim objPPT As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim objPresentation As Presentation
    Dim shapePPTOne As Object


    Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set objPresentation = objPPT.Presentations.Add

    Set objslide = objPresentation.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly) 'you had inLayout???
    objslide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "blah blah"

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C6:G22").Copy
    DoEvents

    Set shapePPTOne = objslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial( _
                DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile, Link:=msoFalse)

    With shapePPTOne
        .Height = 200
        .Left = 50
        .Top = 100
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Excel/PPT/VBA references are all in place and have been double checked thoroughly and i've tried switching the order/priority. The error has happened on multiple different computers all running excel/PPT 2013. I've tried multiple variations of this code but keep running in to the error which leads me to believe it may not be the actual code itself. I've also read that it's usually just easier to adjust the columns/rows in excel, but in my case I need the chart to be posted in a very specific way on the powerpoint slide. Any help someone could offer would be greatly appreciated!

*EDIT - Would also like to point out that pasting and adjusting height/width/etc.. works fine when just using the simple paste method

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out...solution was pretty simple .Height = 200 should be shapePPTOne(1).Height = 200

Comment: Or more generically, Set shapePPTOne = objslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial( _
            DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile, Link:=msoFalse)(1) because pasting returns a shaperange (which might contain 1 or more shapes) and in this case you know you want the first, so tack on the (1)